# What is the meaning of this phrase: "ils ne t'en aiment que davantage"?

Tags: sens

Is this an emphatic phrase to mean "they like you so much (only too much)"? I don't understand the purpose of putting the word "en".

> - Évidemment ! Et ***ils ne t'en aiment que davantage*** !

Comment: The "en" stands for the reason they have to like you that much (a reason we don't know here). I'd translate it as: "And *that* makes them love you even more".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see it as a nearly literal translation of the English notion of:

> “They only like/love you [even] more for that/because of it”

I see the “en” as meaning “for that” or “because of it,” where the “that” or “it” is something you’ve done or said (or a character trait you have) that has made “them” love or like “you” even more than they did before, but I don’t see any implication that their affection for you has reached the point of being excessive.

Comment: Indeed. Your translation hits the nail. I'd never expected there to be a French equivalent of the "they only love you all the more for it" construction. 3UPs :)