# How to interpret « c’en » in « c’en devient d’un ennui mortel »

Tags: expressions

> C'est si facile que **c’en** devient d’un ennui mortel.
>
> = (?) "This is so easy that it’s getting deadly boring."

How does it compare with saying:

> C'est si facile que **ça** devient d’un ennui mortel.

This is the first time I have seen the use of « c’en », and I’m not sure what to make of it. In what other instances would you use « c’en » like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to the the *en* in this [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23230/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-phrase-ils-ne-ten-aiment-que-davantage). The pronoun indexes a prepositional phrase with *de* indicating the source of the feeling.

It's an extension of the core/initial meaning of *de* indicating the point origin of a movement in the direction of the speaker.

"Ça en devient [adjectif]" is something of a set expression (*C'en* is a more literary variant) meaning "It's starting to become [adjective] because of this". You could omit the pronoun without a change in meaning but leaving it in puts more focus on the source of the feeling of boredom as a problem.

Comment: Hi. So basically, does it equal to "ça devient d’un ennui mortel **du fait que c'est si facile**"?

Comment: @LUNA That's a good way of thinking about it, yes. As an aside, "de par sa facilité" would be a more elegant rephrasing of the "du fait que" clause